# Green's Theorem to find area

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

If $$Q_x\ - P_y=1$$ use Green's Theorem to find the area between the $x$-axis and $1$ arch of the cycloid $$x=t\ -sin(t)\ ,\ y=1-cos(t)$$What i've done so far is set $$P(x,x)\ =\ -0.5y, \ Q(x,y)\ =\ 0.5x$$ $$A=\int\int_R(1)\ dA\ ... $$And then I applied Greens Theorem from there by integrating over $0$ to $2\pi$. The answer I'm getting is $0$.

Thanks

Comment: $Q_x - P_y = 1$?

Comment: Yes my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to get the area not by computing $\iint_D 1 \ dA$ but by the associated line integral $\oint_{\partial{D}} \langle P, Q \rangle \cdot d\mathbf{r}$ instead.  If you choose $P(x,y) = - \frac{y}{2}$ and $Q(x,y) = \frac{x}{2}$ then Green's Theorem gives you that $\oint_{\partial{D}} \langle P, Q \rangle \cdot d\mathbf{r}$ is indeed $\iint_D 1 \ dA$, your area.  If you compute this line integral over your curve by brute force (parameterize everything in sight) it comes out to be doable by integration by parts.  Carry on...

Comment: But do *not* forget that you need the entire boundary of the region. So don't forget the closed interval on the $x$-axis. (It happens not to affect your answer in this case, but it often can.)

Comment: Yes, ^this is correct and cannot be overlooked.